# How to install the "Broadcom Wireless Wifi 43142" driver?

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom

So today I wanted to dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 in this system. I know already how to select the "Broadcom Wireless Drivers" on Ubuntu so I tried it in a live iso and it worked! But... Something went wrong. When I tried to go to additional hardware in the gnome application it just pops up the Nvidia drivers.

Can anyone help me?

Edit: `Broadcom BCM43142 802.11 bgn Wi-FI Adapter`

Edit 2: Sorry it is like 23 hours since I posted this but, I just discovered that I need to install bcmwl-kernel-source. However, I don't have ethernet and just have wifi and i'm all doing it offline, since I dual booted it where can I find the link to the latest packages?

Edit 3: So it’s the next day now, I tried to install bcmwl-kernel-source and it says **E: Unable to locate package bcmwl-kernel-source** now what am I supposed to do?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: I asked to give the output of the command, but you posted only a part of it.

Comment: You can always connect using your phone to install drivers.

Comment: But... Where can I find the latest drivers?

Comment: Connect by your phone and `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source`. ;-)

Comment: But remember i'm  **offline in ubuntu** and **I don't have ethernet**

Comment: THE THIRD TIME. You can go online using your phone connected to USB port.

Comment: Yeah I know, the problem is how do I install "bcmwl-kernel-source" using no internet?

Comment: I give up. Try to read my comments again.

Comment: Alright, fine. Yeah sorry for being rude and not understanding, I can go online and connect my phone to the usb port but how do I connect my phone and install bcmwl-kernel-source did you mean that? (Btw using iphone does it still work?)

Comment: Your phone can share internet connection to Ubuntu using USB tethering. This is the easiest way to install drivers. Another way is to take `bcmwl-kernel-source` from the installation media, but it will require some more packages.

Comment: Ohhh, I can connect my iphone and turn on personal hotspot and that's it! I'm so dumb lol anyways going to try this later in the day. It's like 11:00 PM in the Eastern Time Zone so okay see you later! (Again i said this for the third time but i'm really sorry for not understanding you but bye for now.)

Comment: bcmwl-kernel-source is not installing on Ubuntu 20.04